# py3 issue swapping 2 elements in same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap

So i know there are predefined functions but im still practicing the basics.

I want to sort a bunch of integers in a list from lowest to bigest number.

I defined this function:

```
def swap(a, b):
    c = a
    a = b
    b = c

    return a, b
```

And this is what im trying:

```
def low_to_big_sort():   

    n = [2, 1, 63, 6, 8, 5, 12]
    swap(n[0], n[1])

    return n
```

Returns the same list as defined.
What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `swap` function does nothing because it simply swaps the names around without changing the list.

You can fix this in three ways:

- Canonical Python swapping using *tuple unpacking*:

  ```
  n[0], n[1] = n[1], n[0]
  ```
- Actually using the return value from `swap`:

  ```
  n[0], n[1] = swap(n[0], n[1])
  ```
- Passing in an array and a pair of indices to swap:

  ```
  def swapind(l, a, b):
      l[a], l[b] = l[b], l[a]

  swapind(n, 0, 1)
  ```

The first way is the most preferable ("Pythonic"), as it is clear what the operation is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to amend the `list` itself...

```
def swap(L, a, b):
    L[a], L[b] = L[b], L[a]

n = [2, 1, 63, 6, 8, 5, 12]
swap(n, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Ok tuple unpacking answered my question, thanks!
One more question regarding my swap.
How can i make itmultifunctional, to swap integers, indecies, strings, everythin possible?

Comment: @user2710430 you don't... for instance, strings and tuples are immutable so the swapping values at indices wouldn't work (unless you made a copy into something that wasn't - then converted it back)